# Typescript infer sibling key and make it required within array of objects

Tags: typescript

I have a few items that are meant for a table. Each value defined in the cols may optionally appear in the items. However, if checkable is true, checkedValue must be defined as a string and this value of the string must not be undefined in the table items.

```
 <DataTable
cols={[
  { id: "name", title: "Name" },
]}
checkable
checkedValue="_id"
items={[
  {
    _id: "_1",
    name: "Test 1",
  },
  {
    _id: "_2",
  },
  {
    // _id: "_3", <------------------------------
    name: "Test 3",
  },
]}/>
```

Items 1 and 2 are correct, item 3 is incorrect because Id is excluded.

```
type RequiredCheckableKeys<T, C extends boolean> = C extends true
  ? Partial<T> &
      Required<Pick<T, DataTableCheckableProps<T, C>["checkedValue"]>>
  : Partial<T>;

export type DataTableProps<T, K extends T, C extends boolean> = {
  items: RequiredCheckableKeys<K, C>[];
  cols: DataTableCol<T>[];
  size?: keyof Sizes;
  setSort?: (sort: string) => void;
} & DataTableCheckableProps<T, C>;

type DataTableCheckableProps<T, C extends boolean> = C extends true
  ? { checkable: C; checkedValue: Extract<keyof T, string> }
  : { checkable?: C; checkedValue?: never };

export type DataTableCol<T> = {
  id: Extract<keyof T, string>;
  title: string;
  sortable?: boolean;
};

export const DataTable = <T, K extends T, C extends boolean>({
  items,
  cols,
  checkable,
  checkedValue,
}: DataTableProps<T, K, C>) => {
...
```

This is my attempt so far, but it makes all keys required. Since apparently DataTableCheckableProps is recognised as every key in T. However, I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: I have shortened it to the minimum

Comment: Why do you want to exclude the id? Id's are usually the most important part of the data because it is used to identify the item an make them unique in comparence to other items.

Comment: The _id should not be excluded, but there should be a typescript error if it is not present.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAJrkW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. Yes, that works perfectly! Please provide an answer, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to give `DataTable` the following signature:

```
declare const DataTable: <I extends string, K extends string>(
  props: {
    cols: Array<{ id: I, title: string }>,
    checkable: true,
    checkedValue: K,
    items: Array<Record<K, string> & Partial<Record<I, string>>>
  } | {
    cols: Array<{ id: I, title: string }>,
    checkable?: false,
    checkedValue?: never
    items: Array<Partial<Record<I, string>>>
  }) => JSX.Element;
```

It is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `I`, the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `id` properties in the `cols` elements, and `K`, the type of the `checkedValue` property if present.

The `props` parameter should be one of two types; either `checkable` is `true` and `checkedValue` is present and of type `K`, or `checkable` is missing or `false`, and thus `checkedValue` should be missing (an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) whose value is the [impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) is more or less the same as a missing property; well, it could maybe be `undefined`).

If `checkedValue` is present, then `items` should be of type `Array<Record<K, string> & Partial<Record<I, string>>>` which means that it's an array of elements which must contain a `string` property with key `K`, and *may* contain `string` properties with keys from `I`.  (See documentation for [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) and [the `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) if needed.)

If `checkedValue` is absent, then `items` is just of type `Array<Partial<Record<I, string>>>`, meaning that it may have `string` properties with keys from `I`, and is not dependent on `K` at all (which is good, because there'd be nothing from which to infer `K`).

---

Let's test it out:

```
  <DataTable
    cols={[
      { id: "name", title: "Name" },
    ]}
    checkable
    checkedValue="_id"
    items={[ // error! Property '_id' is missing in type '{ name: string; }' 
      {
        _id: "_1",
        name: "Test 1",
      },
      {
        _id: "_2",
      },
      {
        name: "Test 3",
      },
    ]} />
```

Here you get the desired error, which goes away if you add the missing `_id` property:

```
  <DataTable
    cols={[
      { id: "name", title: "Name" },
    ]}
    checkable
    checkedValue="_id"
    items={[
      {
        _id: "_1",
        name: "Test 1",
      },
      {
        _id: "_2",
      },
      {
        _id: "_3",
        name: "Test 3",
      },
    ]} /> // okay
```

And if `checkable` is missing, then no such requirement is imposed:

```
  <DataTable
    cols={[
      { id: "name", title: "Name" },
    ]}
    items={[
      {
        name: "Test 1",
      },
      {
        name: "Test 3",
      },
    ]} /> // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-LTmXHDGVc6AIyaisIPMvZUCFBcBB1k3eDJdhUNqsIF0AJnrtRJvfLY+8TZVrfbAGZR2Oe59zX6BYLhYIfhK-N6y4r7qqDZrytrm-qNcbVxbzlad3e7ZDHS63R6+lLZQf+0rB7Wl1OM6DnOiCdmWK5TmcU4IAOw4Ad2E5QVOsHOouE6OEBLZtogaHgV2a6+rM-oIFAJShFQm58NuNrnJK+6QXcKpNqeTw6pehrXrU5rvl6X6QQ2mEgR28Hjt+0GNgas7YQguFThB3gEURAakWEVBSL6vL8kAA)